# What is this graphed function with asymptotes at π/2 and -π/2?

Tags: graphing-functions, interpolation

I've come across this function with asymptotes at π/2 and -π/2, which crosses the axis at y=1. It doesn't seem to be polynomial or exponential—can anyone figure out what it is?

[image: Graph of function]

The asymptotes and y=1 are exact, but the other points I know of are estimates:

```
-π/2    +∞
-7π/16  5.1000
-3π/8   2.6067
-5π/16  1.7991
-π/4    1.4133
-3π/16  1.2031
-π/8    1.0831
-π/16   1.0200
0       1
π/16    1.0200
π/8     1.0831
3π/16   1.2031  
π/4     1.4133  
5π/16   1.7991  
3π/8    2.6067  
7π/16   5.1000
π/2     +∞
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the secant function:
$$y=\sec(x)$$
where $\sec(x)$ is defined to be $\frac1{\cos(x)}$.

Comment: YUP. Now I feel foolish. Thank you!

Comment: You could also get a similiar looking graph letting $y=-\frac {\pi^2}{4}\frac {1}{(x-\frac \pi 2)(x+\frac \pi 2)} $

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Indeed, I think that's a partial sum of secant's partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Huh, that's pretty interesting! I just thought "let's get the asymptotes and then fix the $x=0$ value".

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD If you get _all_ of the asymptotes, you get the partial fraction decomposition, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD [Helpful graph.](http://i.imgur.com/oXb0jGU.png) If I recall correctly, the $\pm\pi/4$s in the numerators are the residues of the asymptotes. (Secant has no asymptotes at complex numbers, but if it did, they would have to be included.)